# Java servlet- how to recieve updates from an external source?

Tags: java, servlets, httpurlconnection

From a Java servlet on Tomcat, I am sending a post to an external app which launches a 'job' based on the 'message' I send in the post, (the message is sent from an html form).  The external app responds to my post saying that the 'Job was submitted successfully' or 'Job was not submitted successfully'.  The external app is a flask/python application, which launches the 'job', and can then send updates back to my server.

How do I then receive later updates from the external app regarding progress of the job, or job completion/failure?

I'm using an HttpURLConnection to send the post request to the external app:

```
public class Post extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            String message = new String();
            // Data to be posted
            String getMessage = request.getParameter("Message");
            String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

            String url1 = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/GetPost";
            URL obj1 = new URL(url1);
            HttpURLConnection con1 = (HttpURLConnection) obj1.openConnection();
            // add request header
            con1.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con1.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            con1.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            // Send post request
            con1.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr1 = new DataOutputStream(con1.getOutputStream());
            wr1.writeBytes(getMessage);
            wr1.flush();
            wr1.close();            

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Although I do read the post response, (code not included here) I do not know how to receive later updates from the external app.  Open to all suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t understand your needs, but I can advise you:
Servlet maps a link, which is accessed by an external program to return relevant information (such as work progress).
Maybe you can provide me with more details.

Comment: My partner and I are migrating our image processing software from the desktop to a browser-based system.  I am writing the front end in javascript, hosted on Tomcat.  He is writing the back end in Python/flask.  The front end allows users to choose input datasets, set parameters, and submit the image processing job request to the back end.  The back end sends a response indicating whether the job was submitted successfully or not, but the job itself can take several hours to run.

Comment: The back end can send subsequent messages to the front end on, say, job completion, but I don't know how to catch and handle those messages from the front end, especially hours after the initial job request was sent.

Comment: I understand your needs now. It is actually very easy to solve. What you need to solve is the problem of two-way communication. There are many solutions:
1: The front end cyclically sends requests to query processing status at an interval of X minutes.
2: Establish a webSocket channel, the server directly pushes data to the front end, and the front end captures and processes it.

Comment: Thanks.  2) seems better suited.  I'm unclear about the difference between sockets and websockets.  Any insight?